# Forms, How do I get my code to only display info has been submitted if all input boxes have values

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello all I am working on an assignment for my first semester in school and I am trying to get the message "Your information has been submitted to only be displayed if all 3 form inputs have inputs in them. Right now it mostly works but when I click validate after removing last name the message is still there. How do I get the message to disappear if one of the inputs is removed? Also not needed but would love to have a display of @ required for when the input is typed into email. Thanks!

HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stephs.css">  
    <title>BodyBuilding</title>
</head>
<body class="stephsBody">
    <div id="topDisp">
    <nav>
        Index additional links to other pages: <br>
        Click here to go home:
        <a href="blank" target="_blank">
            <img class="stephsImg" id="house" width="100" src="img/house.png" alt="home icon">
        </a>
    </nav>
</div>
    <header class="sBstitle" >
    <h1>Body Building</h1>
</header>
<main class="mainContent">
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <h2>What is it?</h2>
    <div class="readableDecor">
    <p>Body building is a division of fitness that involves lifting weights and developing your muscles. The goal of a lot of bodybuilders is to alter their bodies and develop muscle mass to form parts of their body to be more defined or larger.</p>
    <br>
</div>
<img class="stephsImg" width="300px" src="img/womenDoingCrunches.jpeg" alt="Women doing crunches.">
    <h2>Why?</h2>
    <div class="readableDecor">
    <p>I got involved with bodybuilding during my journey to lose the initial weight I desired. Specifically, I used to be 210lbs. I did research to see what ways I could live a healthier lifestyle and change my body composition and came accross bodybuilding. I began to watch videos of different workout routines and began incoporating that into my schedule.</p>
</div> 
<img class="stephsImg" width="300px" src="img/womenOnLat.jpeg" alt="Women on latpulldown machine.">
    <hr>
    <div class="womenWorkingout">
     
    </div>
    <hr>
    
    <h2>Benefits</h2>
    <div id="benefits" class="readableDecor">
    <p>There are multiple benefits to bodybuilding, while the most obvious answer may seem to be the benefit of muscle definition there are many additional benefits as well.</p>
   <ul>
       <li>Improves Posture</li>
       <li>Better Sleep</li>
       <li>Gaining Bone Density</li>
       <li>Boosts metabilsom</li>
       <li>Improves Strength and Endurance</li>
       <li>Releases endorphins (the bodies "feel good" chemical)</li>
   </ul>
</div>
<img class="stephsImg" id="benefitsImg" width="300px" src="img/womenWithBall.jpeg" alt="Women with a medicine ball.">
<h2>Example of a Workout Schedule</h2>
    <div class="readableDecor">
    <table border="3">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Monday
            </th>
            <th>
                Tuesday
            </th>
            <th>
                Wednesday
            </th>
            <th>
                Thursday
            </th>
            <th>
                Friday
            </th>
            <th>
                Saturday
            </th>
            <th>
                Sunday
            </th>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Glute focused</td>
            <td>Back and Bicep focused</td>
            <td>Quad Focused</td>
            <td>Chest and Triceps focused</td>
            <td>Abdominal focus and strectching</td>
            <td>Rest day with a low intensity walk</td>
            <td>Rest day with recovery yoga</td>
        </tr>
    </table >
</div>
    <br>
    <form class="readableDecor id="f1" method="get"> 
        <legend>Sign up for your own <em>Workout Routine</em></legend>
            <div class="stephsTable">

        Email <input class="inputBox" type="email" placeholder="sophie@example.com"  id="t1"><span class="error" id="t1result"></span>

       <br><br> First Name: <input class="inputBox" type="text" placeholder="Sophie" id="t2"><span class="error" id="t2result"></span>

       <br><br>Last Name: <input class="inputBox" type="text" placeholder="Smith" id="t3"><span class="error" id="t3result"></span>
       <br>
       <br>
       <span id="infoValid"></span>

       <br><br><input type="button" id="btn1" value ="Validate" onclick = "validate()">
            </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
    </main>
    <div class="xDecor">
    <aside class="sideSection">
        <div class="workingOutPhotos">
            
            <img class="stephsImg" width="300px" src="img/womenSquatRack.jpeg" alt="Women squatting in squatrack.">
            <img class="stephsImg" width="300px" src="img/manLifting.jpeg" alt="man lifting a bar, working out.">
            <img class="stephsImg" width="300px" src="img/womenWorkingout.jpeg" alt="Women working out with ropes.">
        </div>
    </aside>
</div>
    <footer class="cpRight">
        <h2 class="cpRight">Stephanie Brandon &copy;</h2>
    </footer>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="validationForStephs.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
//Function to validate form inputs
function validate(){

    var email = document.getElementById("t1").value;

    var fname = document.getElementById("t2").value;

    var lname = document.getElementById("t3").value;

    var isValid = true;

    if(email ==""){

        document.getElementById("t1result").innerHTML=" Email is required";

        isValid=false;

    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("t1result").innerHTML="";
    }

    if(fname ==""){

        document.getElementById("t2result").innerHTML=" First Name is required";

        isValid=false;

    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("t2result").innerHTML="";
    }

    if(lname ==""){

        document.getElementById("t3result").innerHTML=" Last name is required";

        isValid=false;

    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("t3result").innerHTML="";

            document.getElementById("infoValid").innerHTML="Your information has been submitted";
    }
    
   
}
```

CSS

```
#topDisp:hover{
    background-color: #A8ECE7;
    color: white ;
    text-shadow: 2px 1px black;
    transition: .5s;
}
#house:hover{
    background-color: #FDFF8F;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
#topDisp{
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #F4BEEE;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border:2px solid black;
    float: right;
}
.mainContent{
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 30px;
    background-color: #FDFF8F;
    width: 800px;
}
.stephsBody{
    background-color: #A8ECE7;
    color: black;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #D47AE8;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
     font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
     font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
     font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
 }
 .sBstitle{
     margin: 20px;
     padding: 10px;
background-color:#FDFF8F ;
border-radius: 20px;
 }
 .sideSection{
     width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 30px;
     float: right;
     background-color: aliceblue;

 }
 .xDecor{
    width: 250px;
    float: right;
     margin: 13px;
     padding: 10px;
     background-color: #FDFF8F;
 }
#stephsFooter{
    float:inherit;
    bottom: 0px;

 }
 .stephsImg{
     border-radius: 25px;
     padding: 10px;
     margin:5px;
     background-color: #D47AE8;
 }
 .readableDecor{
     background-color: white;
     text-shadow: none;
     border-radius: 15px;
 }
#pathToFrench{
    width: 580px;
}
#brain{
    float: right;
}
#langBen{
    width: 400px;
    float: right;
}
.cpRight{
    position: relative;
    text-align: end;
    width: 900px;
}
#benefits{
    width: 450px;
    float: left;
}
#benefitsImg{
    float: right;
}
.stephsTable{
    background-color: #F4BEEE;
color:black;
font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
}
.error{
    background-color: #FDFF8F;
    margin: 15px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
#infoValid{
    background-color: #FDFF8F;
    margin: 15px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I recommend you create a https://jsfiddle.net/. Makes it easier for someone to view and debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the displaying of the final message is dependent solely on the value of the field `lname`. (You can try to validate the form with last name only and you will see.)

Each of the conditions works separately (which is good for checking whether the one related field is empty or not). But for validating the whole form, it is then necessary to do one extra check of all the fields at once.

So you need to move this line away from the condition of `lname`...

```
document.getElementById("infoValid").innerHTML="Your information has been submitted";
```

... and create new condition checking all the fields together. It could be something like:

```
if(email == "" || fname =="" || lname =="") { // = if email is empty OR fname is empty OR lname is empty
  document.getElementById("infoValid").innerHTML="";
}
else{
  document.getElementById("infoValid").innerHTML="Your information has been submitted";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using validation condition for individual elements in your form, that works properly. You can use a condition checking all the fields for that you can add

```
//Function to validate form inputs
function validate(){

    var email = document.getElementById("t1").value;

    var fname = document.getElementById("t2").value;

    var lname = document.getElementById("t3").value;

    var isValid = true;

    if(email ==""){

        document.getElementById("t1result").innerHTML=" Email is required";

        isValid=false;

    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("t1result").innerHTML="";
    }

    if(fname ==""){

        document.getElementById("t2result").innerHTML=" First Name is required";

        isValid=false;

    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("t2result").innerHTML="";
    }

    if(lname ==""){

        document.getElementById("t3result").innerHTML=" Last name is required";

        isValid=false;

    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("t3result").innerHTML="";

           if(email == "" || fname =="" || lname =="") { 
  document.getElementById("infoValid").innerHTML="";
}
else{
  document.getElementById("infoValid").innerHTML="Your information has been submitted";
}
}
}
```